# Don't know how to make my backend api route work on react

Tags: reactjs, flask, gatsby

I am creating a gatsby app with flask.
I have a route on my backend that returns me a dictionary of user information, but this route has a parameter, you need to pass the uid of the user to get the list you want.
At this point is working i can return lists of different users changing the uid.
Now i want to make the react front end with this route, i've tried but i have no clue what i am doing.

Backend api code(this func returns me a list depending on what uid i insert in the route):

```
@app.route('/user/<uid>', methods=['GET'])
@jwt_required
def user_details(uid):

    user = ldap.get_object_details(uid)
    return jsonify(user)
```

returned dictionary:

```
 {
  "cn": [
    "Turanga Leela"
  ], 
  "description": [
    "Mutant"
  ], 
  "employeeType": [
    "Captain", 
    "Pilot"
  ], 
  "mail": [
    "leela@planetexpress.com"
  ], 
  "ou": [
    "Delivering Crew"
  ], 
  "sn": [
    "Turanga"
  ], 
  "uid": [
    "leela"
  ]
}
```

So i already have a page that displays me the users that i have.
What i want is to click on a name in this list and go to a page where i only display that user information, using my new route.

this is the code from the front-end user list(displays a list of users):

```
users.jsx

export default function User ({ data })  {
  const classes = useStyles()

  return (

    <div className={classes.root}>
      <h1>Users</h1>
      <Table className={classes.table} size="small">
        <TableHead>
          <TableRow>
            <TableCell align="left">User</TableCell>
             <Link to='/details'></Link>
          </TableRow>
        </TableHead>
        <TableBody>
            {data.map(user => (
            <TableRow>
              <TableCell align="left">{user} </TableCell>

            </TableRow>
          ))}
        </TableBody>
      </Table>
    </div>
  )
}
```

i've also created a new page userdetails.jsx to fetch my user details data but i can't display it:

```
userdetails.jsx

export default function UserDetails ({ data })  {
  const classes = useStyles()

  return (

     <div className={classes.root} >
       <h1>User Details</h1>
       <Table className={classes.table} size="small">
         <TableHead>
           <TableRow>
             <TableCell align="left">cn</TableCell>
             <TableCell align="left">description</TableCell>
             <TableCell align="left">employeeType</TableCell>
             <TableCell align="left">mail</TableCell>
             <TableCell align="left">ou</TableCell>
             <TableCell align="left">sn</TableCell>
             <TableCell align="left">uid</TableCell>
           </TableRow>
         </TableHead>
         <TableBody>
           {data.map(row => (
             <TableRow>
               <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
               </TableCell>
               <TableCell align="left">{row.cn}</TableCell>
               <TableCell align="left">{row.description}</TableCell>
               <TableCell align="left">{row.employeeType}</TableCell>
               <TableCell align="left">{row.mail}</TableCell>
               <TableCell align="left">{row.ou}</TableCell>
               <TableCell align="left">{row.sn}</TableCell>
               <TableCell align="left">{row.ui}</TableCell>
             </TableRow>
           ))}
         </TableBody>
       </Table>
     </div>
   )
}
```

i am fetching like this :

```
userdetails.js

import React from "react"

import Layout from "../components/layout"
import UserDetails from "../components/userdetails"
import MainComponentWrapper from "../components/mainComponentWrapper"


const IndexPage = () => (
  <Layout>
    <MainComponentWrapper url="http://localhost:5000/user/<uid>">
      <UserDetails />

    </MainComponentWrapper>
  </Layout>
)
export default IndexPage
```

Comment: Look up react-router https://reacttraining.com/react-router/

Comment: The `returned list` is not a list.

Comment: wich error do you get?

Comment: In your `IndexPage` component, you do not pass any props such as the data object. As far as I understand your `<MainComponentWrapper url="http://localhost:5000/user/<uid>">` should fetch the data object? Or where do you fetch it? If you pass no props to `<UserDetails />` such as `<UserDetails data={data}/>` there is no data to display.

Comment: @EliteRaceElephant i am exporting the data there to the userdetails, thats not the problem, the probem is how to make the user list  table with links to the new route that shows the detail of each user